# Как получить «Мои подписки» через YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Не могу получить «Мои подписки» через YouTube API. Мой запрос выглядит так:

**GET**:
    `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mySubscribers=true&maxResults=10&access_token=token`

**И получаю такой результат:**

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#subscriptionListResponse",
 "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/UqNA2mAcD_4Y5kPEvnJbwWfXLng\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Как видно, никаких «Моих подписок» здесь **не показывается**. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиграл [с API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#try-it), вот такой запрос работает:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: @Sergiks, о, отлично! Спасибо огромное, геморный этот API ютуба.